# How do I configure Emacs to display of line numbers permanenty

Tags: init-file, customize, line-numbers

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Displaying-the-current-line-or-column.html

```
M-x (global-display-line-numbers-mode)
```

But after I do C-x C-c then it's not configed.
How do I make config permanently for display line number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`M-x customize-variable RET global-display-line-numbers-mode RET`, and click the `Toggle` button, and then press the `Apply and Save` button

At the end of the process your init file----see the `*Messages*` buffer for this info-----will have `elisp` code.

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 '(global-display-line-numbers-mode t))
```

Copy the following snippet to your `*scratch*` buffer,

```lisp
(info "(emacs) Specific Customization")
```

and do `C-x C-e` at the end of the buffer.  It will take you to the manual page for how to customize `Emacs`, which is [`customize-option`: *Specific Customization (GNU Emacs Manual)*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specific-Customization.html#index-customize_002doption)

---

The official `GNU Emacs Manuals` (the `HTML` ones online) aren't searchable.

To access searchable `HTML` manuals, visit [The Emacs Editor | Emacs Docs](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/emacs/The-Emacs-Editor).   In this case, the entry is [49.1.6 Customizing Specific Items | Emacs Docs](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/emacs/Specific-Customization#m-x-customize-option-ret-option-ret) On the top menu bar, you can access the docs for many commonly used packages.

The  `Emacs Docs` has a `helm` like search menu which offers suggestion base on what you type, which is nice.  (`GNU Emacs Manual`-s suck, I know that)

***`Emacsdocs.org` is a nice place to search `Emacs Manuals`***

[image: Emacsdocs.org is a nice place to search Emacs Manuals]

Comment: cannot customize, init file was not fully loaded

Comment: Oh, you have a bigger problem.  Delete the init file (or move it to some backup directory)  and start building it from scratch ...

Comment: Updated the response a bit ...